# sql deleting duplicate row

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL

```
Id   owner_id   amount
1     100        1000
2     101        2000
3     100        3000
4     104        800
5     100        1200
```

i want only one owner_id i don't want 100 multiple times, but i want amount of all owner_id 100 i,e that amount should be added(i,e. 1000+3000+12000) if i delete duplicate Owner_id row. how to do it

And one more issue that owner_id from another table, how to get Owner name from another table. How to add join to get name of the owner

Comment: if you want to store Amount (i,e. 1000+3000+12000) store in same table, Or store in second table that contains amounts and update the value in Main table that is with owner_id, Amount... so you will have only unique owner in table

Comment: Remember that after doing the data cleanup you should add a unique key in the `owner_id` column of the table to avoid further duplicated data.

Comment: You are either missing your c# code in your question or your SQL script. As is, your question only says what you want to get, but it is missing your actual problem/question

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```sql
-- Acumulate all the amount to be able to do the cleanup
UPDATE table SET amount = sumAmount
FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT owner_id, SUM(amount) sumAmount
FROM table
GROUP BY owner_id) x ON x.owner_id = t.owner_id;

-- Delete duplicated data
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY owner_id, amount ORDER BY Id) row
    FROM table)
DELETE CTE WHERE row <> 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `PARTITION BY owner_id ORDER BY Id`? BTW, nice answer, this is the first one that addreses on the cleanup

Comment: updated to order by Id, this should work or at least can closely give the idea to work as required with few twitches

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  owner_id,
  SUM(amount) total_amount
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  owner_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select owner_id, sum(amount) from table_name group by owner_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with the SUM Function, here is a reference: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

SUM sums the amount of a the column which you insert, here: amount.

Please be aware that some functions only works if all other selected columns within another function OR grouped by.

```
SELECT
  owner_id,
  SUM(amount) total_amount
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  owner_id
```